# Can we install Oracle Database on Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: ubuntu, database, windows-subsystem-for-linux, oracle

I tried to install Oracle Database on Windows Subsystem for LINUX and when i tried to execute command
./runInstaller following error occured

```
ERROR: Unable to verify the graphical display setup. This application requires X display. 
Make sure that xdpyinfo exist under PATH variable.

No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
```

Can you help me to solve  this error? Can we install Oracle Database on Windows Subsystem for LINUX? Screenshot of the error [is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjmAG.png)

Comment: Do you have an X11 display?

Comment: Oracle lists supported platforms on its website.  You're unlikely to find WSL as a supported platform.

Comment: Actually I'm new to LINUX environment and I'm not sure whether I have X11 display or not. Can you please help to setup X11 display?

Comment: @bhanuvinayes That would be another question. Also note it is Gnu/Linux not Linux. Linux is the kernel (like the NT kernel is part of Windows 10), Gnu/Linux is the OS. Using the wrong name causes confusion e.g. WSL1 had no Linux: it was Gnu+Linux - Linux.

Answer (score 1):

WSL does not come with, or install an X Window server, by default.

You can, however, install a 3rd party X Window server such as `xming` or `vcxsrv`, both of which I have successfully used with WSL Ubuntu.

Comment: I have just remembered a similar problem setting us oracle on a Gnu/Linux server. The person doing it screamed why do I need a display system to run a database? I had a look, and we decided to install a dump X11-server. Not connected to a physical. I can remember what, there are X11-vnc servers. But I think what we used was even lighter, and incapable of doing anything display like, but did provide the services that oracle needed. I would do a search (but not mention WSL).